# Irresponsible Behavior Putting Jobs at Risk

Tags: management, team

We're having big cutbacks at our company.  Next week, our CFO is planning on making an unannounced visit to our branch.  He will be taking a look at our operations, staff, and processes.  After visiting all of the branches, he will be deciding which branches  to keep and which to close.

I only know about this because I am an Operations Manager who is in a committee (with 3 other managers) that will be presenting the branch while he is here.  We have strict instructions that we are not to inform the employees of his upcoming visit or give any indication to adjust their behavior this next week.

This has me troubled, because while we are a very organized and productive branch, we've had a big problem in the last year: people sleeping the bathroom stall.  It started off with one person locking the stall and taking a nap while sitting down, now there are a lot of people who are doing it.  Last week, I went to the bathroom and counted 4 people snoring in the stall, and another 2 I suspect were probably sleeping.

I fear that the CFO will hold this against us if he hears people snoring while he is taking a bio break.  I'd hate to see our entire branch get axed as the result of a few irresponsible people.  But I really fear that if I send a "No sleeping the bathroom!" e-mail around, that will be seen as telling employees to act differently this next week.

What is the best way to remedy this situation without getting myself or my branch in trouble?  Is there anything like a slow acting tear gas that I can use in the bathroom that will allow people to use the bathroom in peace, but discourage sleeping?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51974/discussion-on-question-by-anon-irresponsible-behavior-putting-jobs-at-risk).

Answer (score 3):

You are faced with a basic dilemna : are you most loyal to the orders given to you, or to the people you work with ?

If you feel most loyal to your teams, you do not need a big email warning. Say that to a couple guys during a coffee break, word will spread **very** quickly.

If you feel most loyal to the orders/management and do not want to see the deparment axed, you could note carefully who sleeps or not, and confront/report them. This kind of behaviour generally continues until someone points it out. If they refuse to stop, report them for the greater good.

Last possibility : if you are fine with people sleeping there (I would not be) you might want to introduce the CFO officially to the teams during a tour, which will give a bit of time for the employees to react.